# How to create more test account when using Mocha to test Solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity, testrpc, testing, mocha

By default there are only 10 test accounts being created, how do I create more when using Mocha to test smart contract?

I assume Mocha creates a testRPC instance somehow, there must be a way to modify that settings.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume Mocha creates a testRPC instance somehow...

No, it is you who needs to run Ganache (formerly known as TestRPC) before you run your Mocha test.

In this common setup, the Ganache process runs as a server, and your Mocha test runs as a client.

The protocol of communication between them is typically Web3 (over HTTP or WebSocket).

Here is an example of how you can start a Ganache process which initializes 15 accounts with 1 ether each:

```
ganache-cli
    --port=8545
    --gasPrice=0x1
    --gasLimit=0x1fffffffffffff
    --account=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000A,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000B,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000C,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000D,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E,1000000000000000000
    --account=0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F,1000000000000000000
```

What you see here are the private keys of these accounts, and Ganache will print their public addresses when it starts.

Note that in contrast with a real Ethereum Node (like Parity or Geth), Ganache keeps all of these accounts unlocked, so you can easily run your test without having to sign each transaction with the private key of the account that you send it with.

Therefore your test will not run when you try to execute it on a real Ethereum Node - you will have to either unlock the accounts first (highly not recommended), or at least before every transaction (also not recommended), or sign each transaction with the private key of the account that you send it with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ganache for test, it give you the possible to have up to 100 accounts. Click config button, then Account & Keys.